# PowerShell get-help don't see synopsis and other things

Tags: powershell

I am running PS2.0 on Win8.

When I run "get-help Get-ChildItem", I only see NAME and SYNTAX, where is the SYNOPSIS, RELATED LINKS and other info?

[image]

Comment: Windows 8 comes with PowerShell 3.0 preinstalled. At least mine did. Where did you get 2.0 from? (Type `$PSVersionTable` to see the version.)

Comment: I installed the 2.0 by "Add features".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run PowerShell 2 Windows 8 by passing the `-version` switch to powershell.exe:

```
powershell.exe -version 2.0
```

If you run PowerShell 2 like that, then the help appears to work as expected:

```
PS > help gci

NAME
    Get-ChildItem

SYNOPSIS
    Gets the items and child items in one or more specified locations.
[...]
```

Comment: it works when I run powershell.exe -version 3.0

Comment: @smwikipedia, I did an `Update-Help` in PS3. I wonder if you need to do that as well? Note that you will need to run PS3 as administrator to do that.

Answer (score -1):

Use

```
PS > Get-Help Get-Member -full
```

The `full` parameter will get you all available help for specific subject

You will see Links, Examples, Notes, Outputs, Inputs and detailed Synopsis

Comment: sorry, but -full doesn't work for me. I am using PowerShell 2.0 on Win8.

Comment: get-help returns what I want if I run the Powershell -version 3.0